# How did mailman add itself to all virtual hosts?

Tags: centos, mailman

I'm trying to install and configure Mailman on a CentOS server and encountered something weird.

I installed mailman (2.1.9) using the package provided by CentOS (5.11).

I use the server to host multiple subdomains, and followed the instructions to add an alias "mailman" to one of the subdomains. However, I then noticed all other subdomains had aquired a /mailman/ alias too. Even removing the original subdomain didn't help.

I'm quite puzzled as I can't find any changes to Apache's configuration that would add an alias to all subdomains. I've had to remove mailman from the server completely until I can fix this issue.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailman puts a configuration file at /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf which globally defines that alias:

```
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/
<Directory /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/>
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you don't want that alias on all subdomains, taking out this configuration should help.
Note that if you simply remove that file it may get placed there again if you do a `yum update` which includes a mailman update.
Commenting it out is possibly the better solution here (or replacing it with an empty file).

Comment: Thanks! Bit embarrassed I didn't spot that :-)
Good tip about commenting too.